# Filter rows in a CSV file and then sort them based on a column

Tags: python, csv

Trying to parse the data file (below) to find only the rows where the user started before a certain date. then order the values from the words column from these rows in ascending order (by start date)

```
id, name, start_date, role, end_date, words
657, mystical, 1351140260, cleaner, 1951140260, very lazy
1987, kanyau, 1451189768, watchman, 1539742445, sleeping
```

Can anyone assist?

P.S: newbie here but here is what I have been playing around with.

```
date_pivot = "6/09/2010 00:00:00"
d = datetime.strptime(date_pivot, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
date_pivot = time.mktime(d.timetuple())
dp = int(date_pivot)
infile = csv.DictReader(open("sample_data.csv","rb"), delimiter=",")
previous_users = [row for row in infile if row['start_date'] < 'dp']
#print previous_users
with open('final_test.csv','wb') as fou:
    dw = csv.DictWriter(fou, previous_users.keys())
    dw.writeheader()
    dw.writerow(my_dict)
```

Comment: It's unclear what you meant by "..., then order the values from the words column from these rows in ascending order (by start date)" because the values in the words column don't have start dates (or it would be the same for all of them). Please [edit] your question and explain how do you want things sorted/reordered better.

Answer (score 0):

Should be fairly simple. Since you need to type convert and do lookup for your key function, a `lambda` is simplest:

```
previous_users.sort(key=lambda row: int(row['start_date']))
```

A note: Passing `previous_users.keys()` to `DictWriter` as the fieldnames is doubly wrong. One, you'd need to do `previous_users[0].keys()` (after verifying it was non-empty), because `previous_users` is a `list` of `dict`, not `dict`. Two, `dict`s have no defined ordering, so your output columns will likely be rearranged. If that's not a problem, so be it. But you probably want to explicitly pass the field names in the desired order or read them in the right order from the `DictReader`, e.g. `csv.DictWriter(fou, infile.fieldnames)`

Additional typo note: Presumably you want to compare `int(row['start_date']) < dp`; you need to convert to `int`, and you want to compare to the value in `dp`, not the string `"dp"`.